# label Input align in RTL css form

Tags: css, forms

I have RTL form. But Input and label are not Regular in a row.

HTML:

```
<div class="searchfield">

    <label for="name">name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" />
</div>
<div class="searchfield">
    <label for="name">last name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" />
</div>
<div class="searchfield">
    <label for="name">tel :</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" />
</div>
<div class="searchfield">
    <label for="name">id :</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchfield{margin:10px 20px 0 0;}
.label {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left:4px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 22px;
    }

input.input {
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    width:135px; height:20px; background-color:#fafafa; font-size:11px;}
```

Online DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/uEKkF/1/

i need to This Picture : [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There were two things wrong:

1. Your selector for the labels was prefixed by `.`, so it was looking for any element with the class of `label`, rather than a `label` element.
2. No width was explicitly set on that element. When block elements are floated without an explicit width, they only extend the width of its content, which in this case was variable.

You can see the fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/uEKkF/3/